# Switch jQuery toggle on mouseout and timer

Tags: jquery, toggle

In my website i got a button. If u click it, a dropdown will come. If you click it again. It'll disappear.
I use the jQuery function TOGGLE for it.
Now i want the following. If you move out of the dropdown for 2 seconds, or click somewhere outside the dropdown. it has to disappear again.

Is there a way to switch the Toggle function with a timer and click outside?
This is the code:

```
$(Ar3).addClass(aU);
$('.ContextMenuLink').toggle(function () {
    $(hP).css('background', '#fff');
    $('.ContextMenuTxt').css('color', '#6b8592');
    $(CM).css('display', 'block');
    $(Ar3).addClass(aD).removeClass(aU);
}, function () {
    $(hP).css('background', 'none');
    $('.ContextMenuTxt').css('color', '#fff');
    $(CM).css('display', 'none');
    $(Ar3).removeClass(aD).addClass(aU);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your timer to issue a `$('.ContextMenuLink').click()`.

As for the outside click, I would do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function outSideClick(e){
    if(e.target != $('.ContextMenuLink')[0]){
        $('.ContextMenuLink').click();
        $(document).unbind('click',outSideClick);
    })
});
```

You should also remember to unbind this event whenever you close the drop-down by clicking on it or using the timer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment! It helped allot and got it working!